# SELECT * FROM `table` does not return all columns in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I execute `SELECT * FROM table`, the returned rowset does not contain all of the columns in the table. It does not contain the columns that were recently added. Though, the `structure` tab in phpMyAdmin shows the new columns. And if I query directly like `SELECT new_column_name FROM table`, the column values also do appear.

This problem is present both if I query the table via PHP or phpMyAdmin.

Interesting enough, if I run `SELECT *, new_column_name FROM table`, the `new_column_name` values are duplicated.

What might the reason for such weird behaviour, and how do I restore the default behaviour showing all columns using `*`?

UPDATE:
I have flushed the table cache and I have restarted the mysql server, but nothing changes.

UPDATE:
Storage engine is InnoDB

UPDATE:
Before adding new columns, I drag-and-dropped a column header to another place to switch the columns' places. But after adding the columns, I clicked `restore column order`, so it shouldn't have had any influence...

UPDATE:
After checking what is returned if I run the query via command-line, I now see that the problem is actually only with phpMyAdmin (the command line returns the new columns among others). Double-checking what I was doing in PHP showed that I was explicitly selecting specific columns. **So, now the problem persists only in phpMyAdmin.** What might be wrong with it?

Comment: Perhaps some (mysql) caching?

Comment: I have flushed the table cache, but nothing changes.

Comment: @davey: That would be my guess, the `*` queries the database for the containing columns. It's possible that the metadata isn't updated yet.

Comment: Are you adding the column and execute the select * query over the same connection object?

Comment: What is your storage-engine? What if you try to query your table in `mysql` command-line client?

Comment: @Stefan, I have added the column via phpMyAdmin, filled it with values with phpMyAdmin, and now trying to get values also with phpMyAdmin. I'm not sure what are you talking about, but I suspect it's not the reason of the problem, because the problem persists anyway.

Comment: What does `SHOW CREATE MYTABLE` display?

Comment: would you do a `select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'` and see if the result returns all fields?

Comment: @revo, `select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'` returns the new columns among others.

Comment: @Strawberry, `REPAIR TABLE mytable` returns a message stating that The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair.

Comment: that's so weird. did you try to optimize table?

Comment: @revo, yes I did optimize the table, nothing changes.

Comment: please add spaces or do redundant works on query which won't change the results but the typing: `select   * /* a comment */ from table as m where 1 = 1`

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, thanks to your comment, I tried to run the query in command line. Updated the question to correspond new info.

Comment: @revo, tried `select * /* a comment */ from table as m where 1 = 1` - nothing changes.

Comment: I now suspect the problem is linked with changing the order of columns in phpMyAdmin (see previous update). Maybe it restored to the order of columns that existed before the new columns were added. But how do I delete these column order settings?

Comment: @Maksym I had same issue and you were right, deleting all domain cookies helped.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve quickly is to just duplicate the table, then drop the old one and rename the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you run custom query with additional columns, which does not exists, and reordered, it will happen. Just delete cookies and order will be restored.
Replicate:

1. Run: `SELECT 1 as aa, 2 as bb FROM table_name;
2. Reorder columns.
3. Try selecting everything, Phpmyadmin will show lots of errors.
4. Delete cookies to reset custom order and fix issue.

p.s. some credits to @Maksym

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem just now.

Fixed it by changing the Storage Engines from InnoDB to MyISAM, then back to InnoDB again.